# Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<never>'. Even though I have filtered the settled results so that only rejection remain

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I want to extract all rejected promises. However, even though I filter out the promises that have been rejected, my typescript interpreter still shows that the promises could still be fulfilled. It occurs in the code below

```js
const promises = .... // generate a bunch of promises
const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

const errors = results.filter(result => result.status === 'rejected')

// Errors out here -> 'Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<never>''
const reasons = errors.map(error => error.reason)
```

Why does it show this `Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<never>'.` error even though I have filtered the list to make sure it only contains rejected promise? How can I fix this?

Comment: You will need to cast `errors` to the expected type, because typescript cannot infer this simply by comparing the status of all elements with "rejected".

Answer (score 9):

## Problem

The type for `Array.filter` looks like this:

```
filter<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
```

– [TypeScript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1367](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5d2e62a810d25db3a9745059ddc0e2ca468eb34c/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1367)

You'll be able to see the return type is `S` which is an extension of `T` where `T` is the type of `value`. In your situation, the `value` is `results` which has a type of `PromiseSettledResult<void>[]` hence the error you have.

## Solution

TypeScript by itself isn't able to understand that `result.status === 'rejected'` filters the array to only be rejected promises. You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to help TypeScript narrow your type:

```
const errors = results.filter(
  (result): result is PromiseRejectedResult =>
    result.status === 'rejected'
)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=8&ssc=4&pln=5&pc=1#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLbFRACgEoYBvAKBhikxGRgAcAndbVEAUxBgF4YBtAAos2nAHRMu6ADYA3DsQA0MYa3YcJHAFYcoyYgF0YAemMwA5hwgcmwZBxjAYAIyRQAFjHRxGI9SEpqWnpJEARpZG4+YAB3PHpVUQ1gaWkAZQ5kZGkOABMCZjVOECJyQJoIOhgbFiYomFDwyLE4VAibAkCqAkaIogAuBq4mmHYVP04AJW1de1zpsIjeAD4uqiHF5DE6OwQonj4AckkdPTzDwNLy4KHQWl5qplqQMVwGAhr0JhXH2s07iClAC+QA)